# Spring MVC приложение при конфигурации через Java файл выдает ошибку 404. Среда разработки Intelij Idea

Tags: spring-mvc

Проблема в том, что это элементарное spring MVC, http://localhost:8080 нормально открывает index.jsp. но http://localhost:8080/hello не открывает hello.html(пробовал переделывать на hello.jsp и даже прямо в контроллере расширение ставить).

текущие JDK 20, но пробовал и на 16, 17, 19
Tomcat текущий 9, но пробовал и на 10. В настройках деплоя артефакт пустой оставил.
Зависимости spring пробовал и 5 версию.
jakarta тоже просило при Tomcat 10
Такая проблема не у меня первого, но ответа не нашел.
Зависимости: spring-core(6.1.0), spring-context(6.1.0), spring-web(6.1.0), spring-webmvc(6.1.0), thymeleaf-spring5(3.0.11.RELEASE), jakarta.servlet-api(6.0.0), javax.servlet-api(4.0.1)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Проверь версию Томката. Поставь 10 версию, если твоя версия ниже.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Проблему решил тем что начал использовать spring boot. Там все прекрасно работает. А том случае я использовал и разные версии зависимостей, томкат 8,9,10, разные jdk и ничего. Даже качал с git чужую якобы рабочую версию и все равно она не рабочая). Spring boot в общем решение)